# Finding reduce-reduce conflict examples

Tags: parsing, dfa, lr-grammar, reduce-reduce-conflict

While many questions are asking to help solve reduce-reduce conflicts, I don't have any of those and I am actually asking your help to find some.

I am writing documentation and exercices about LR(1) parser conflicts. While I could find some interesting shift-reduce conflicts such as order of operation or the dangling else conflict, I cannot find examples of reduce-reduce conflicts that are both subtle and arise with as few rules as possible.

For a change, could you help me find problems instead of solutions?